# delete characters in notepad++ after #

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a chunk of HTML files that need removal of code.

```
<a href="something.htm#CDCCCABI">
```

should baiscally become

```
<a href="something.htm">
```

Basically in all the files, there are anchors starting with # and followed by a random 8 digit word. Need to remove the anchor from all the files.

Have been trying to do this using RegEx but not being able to. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

Find what: `#\w{8}`
Replace with: `nothing`

Comment: @user3710846: Glad it helps. Feel free to accept the answer ;-)